# Read 10 digits in a Java array and print them out in reverse

Tags: java, netbeans

I have some problems with an exercise I can do to learn coding with arrays.
It's basically my questions title. It's supposed to give me 9,8,7,6,...,0 but it just prints out 0,0,0,0,0,...

Can anyone see what I do wrong here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int intArray[] = new int[9];
    for (int i = intArray.length -1; i>=0; i--);{
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(intArray));
}
}
```

Comment: You need to read this:  ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Remove semicolon after the loop, and print a single digit, not the entire array at once. Make sure the array is filled with digits that you want to print in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

You create array with lenght 9, but you don't set any values in it, so integer instantiated with zeros by default.

You want this:

```
        int intArray[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

and cycle is wrong as well, reverse print should be like this:

```
int intArray[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (int i = intArray.length -1; i>=0; i--){
        System.out.println(intArray[i]);
    }
```

What you did - printed whole array. In my example I print i element of array on every iteration.

And there were extra semicolon after for(...)

UPDATE: there are another ways to get array filled with 10 digits. One more option is another for cycle:

```
int intArray[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = i;
    }
for (int i = intArray.length -1; i>=0; i--){
        System.out.println(intArray[i]);
    }
```

Brings the same result, and can be more handy if you have really big array

Comment: I guess the "Read 10 digits in a Java array" part of the question is important here because there are simpler ways to write the digits 0 to 9 in reverse order.

Comment: As author didn't expected zeros I just have explained why he gets them.
You mean cycle for filling array? as for me it's overhead for 10 digits, but I'll update answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code have two error .

1. You need to set the value of array
2. Remove the semicolon immediately from for loop ,so your loop run the statement.

**Run below code**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        //need to initalized your array
        int intArray[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        for (int i = intArray.length -1; i>=0; i--){
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
        }
    }
```